# npm install error for grep in windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install mkdirp package on windows via npm & getting below error.

```
[Error: You need some version of `grep` on your PATH to compile the gnu-tools version of grep!] '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download grep and have it in your PATH.

If you have any unix style tools you can do it via a package manager, otherwise you'll just have to download the exe from GNU.

Adding it to your path is different per OS. On Windows it's under explorer->this pc(right click) -> properties -> advanced system settings -> environment variables.

Once your PATH includes a reference to grep.exe then you should be fine. I've kept it a bit vague here because it depends completely on your OS.

Answer (score 1):

[`mkdirp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) is not cross-platform, so It won't work on Windows without external libs. You need something like [`make-dir`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-dir) or [`make-dir-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-dir-cli) instead.